# Include File Get New Content Last Changed

Tags: php

I've created a file called "settings.php"

and inside settings.php

```
<?php 
return '123'; 
?>
```

And in index.php I updated the content of settings.php using file_put_contents

```
$config = '1234';
file_put_contents('settings.php', '<?php return ' . var_export($config), true) . ';');
```

After successfully updated the content, in index.php I call the settings.php

```
$config = include(BASEPATH.'settings.php');
```

But after I print_r, the result is

```
123
```

and after sometimes waiting (maybe 5 up to 15 seconds), I do refresh page again and the content changed to

```
1234
```

The problem is, why the updated content not directly changed after I refresh the page?
how to get the newly updated content from settings.php after I change its content.

Comment: What are the server details? Is this some kind of "free hosting" set-up?

Comment: I use my own hosting and it is paid hosting.

Comment: It could be adding it to the cache so when you refresh it’s just pulling the cached content instead of renewing it.

Comment: Is there a way to always clear cache when page reload?

Comment: Its not good idea to clear cache when page reload. You will lose performance. Clear for  specific file only.

Comment: Could you please confirm the real code in your `index.php`. In the sample code, there are a number of errors. Also, if `$config = '1234';` and `$config = include(BASEPATH.'settings.php');` are in the same file, then you are making pointless requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what cache solution is on your server thru phpinfo().

Then you can search solution.

In first you can try this if opcache solution is installed on your server:

```
if (function_exists('opcache_invalidate')) {
    opcache_invalidate('second.php');//Reset file cache
}
```

or this for normal raw files:

```
clearstatcache();
```